# react redirect after login with verification of the jwt token validity

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I log I want to redirect to the /admin page, but admin page and other page are in private route so no one can go to theses pages without authentication who's verified in app.js with the jwt check token.
the problem is when I log I don't get redirected to the /admin page it leave me on the /login page and log me an 401 error code cause the request was send to early and the cookie is not on the navigator at this moment

here is my different component
App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Routes from "./components/Routes";
import axios from "axios";
import { UidContext } from "./components/AppContext";

const App = () => {
  const [uid, setUid] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  let config = {
    method: "get",
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}jwt`,
    withCredentials: true,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchToken = async () => {
      await axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            setLoading(false);
          } else {
            setUid(false);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
    if (uid === true) {
      fetchToken();
    }
  }, [uid, loading]);

  return (
    <UidContext.Provider value={{ uid, setUid }}>
      <Routes Loading={loading} />
    </UidContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

here is my route and private route component :
route

```
const Index = ({ Loading }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={home} />
          <Route path="/login" exact component={login} />
          {!Loading && (
            <>
              <PrivateRoute path="/admin" exact component={admin} />

              <PrivateRoute path="/generatekey" exact component={generatekey} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/userlist" exact component={userlist} />
            </>
          )}
          <Route component={error_page} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

private

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const uid = useContext(UidContext);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        uid === true ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  );
};
```

App context component for uidcontext

```
import {createContext} from "react";

export const UidContext = createContext();
```

and a part of login component

```
  async function handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log(login, password)
    await axios(config)
      .then((response) => {
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "";
        setUid(true);
        history.push("/admin");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = error;
      });
  }
```

Comment: _"401 error code cause the request was send to early and the cookie is not on the navigator at this moment"_ can you explain?  Sounds like you already know what the problem is. Keep in mind that a route that is only protected on the client-side is not secure

Comment: yeah I think I know the problem I just don’t know how to fix it. btw i know the route are not really protected but all the information are server side and protected by the authentification so even if they can access to this route they can’t see anything

Comment: In my opinion the app.js component send the request to check the JWT before the token who’s inside the response of the login request has arrived

Comment: Hm. There is not much code and yet a lot of code. You may have to drop to debugger to see what is happening, I have no suggestions, sorry!